# How do I remove duplicate vowels from a string?

Tags: c

**Question:** Define an int function that removes all consecutive vowel repetitions from a string. The function should return the number of vowels removed and present the string without duplicates.

I am PT so Vogais is Vowels; Digite uma String is Write one String. A String sem duplicados fica assim ' %s ' e foram retiradas %d vogais is The string without duplicates is ' %s ' and where removed %d vowels.

**Explanation:** In portuguese we have some words with two consecutive vowels like: **coordenador, coordenação** (chqrlie example). But in thouse cases should be ignored in the context of this problem.

**Problem:** When I test a string like 'ooooo' it says the string without duplicate vogals is 'oo' and where removed 3 vowels. But it should be 'o' and 4 vowels removed. Another example with error is 'Estaa e umaa string coom duuuplicadoos', I am getting ' Esta e uma string com duplcdos ' and 8 vowels removed.

**Note:** This is a simple question so there isn't need to complicate. It only askes the **consecutive duplicate vowels**. The cases 'oOoO' -> 'oO' ,'abAb'->'abAb','abab' -> 'ab','aba'-> 'aba',... are in another chapter XD.

```
int Vogais(char *s) {
    if (*s == 'A' || *s == 'a' || *s == 'E' || *s == 'e'
     || *s == 'I' || *s == 'i' || *s == 'O' || *s == 'o'
     || *s == 'U' || *s == 'u') return 1;
    return 0;
}

int retiraVogaisRep(char *s) {
    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; s[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (s[i] == s[j] && Vogais(&s[j]) == 1) {
                res++;
                for (int k = j; s[k] != '\0'; k++) {
                    s[k] = s[k + 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}

int main() {
    char s[38];
    printf("Digite uma String:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", s);
    int res = retiraVogaisRep(s);
    printf("A String sem duplicados fica assim ' %s ' e foram retiradas %d vogais.\n", s, res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The consecutive `return res;` statements are superfluous.  Remove the one at the far end of the `if` line.

Comment: Do you mean duplicate, or consecutive ?

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Consecutive duplicate

Comment: When you remove the second of 3 consecutive vowels, you don't check the third (fourth, …).  Probably you should loop over consecutive same vowels before copying the string.

Comment: But an complexity of  N^4 just for a duplicate function

Comment: There is a trivial optimation (which would make the program a bit more comnplex): if the preceeding character is not a vowel you can just copy. You could also retain the downcased character during the loop.

Comment: Ohh nice one I didn't think in that one will try it @wildplasser

Comment: I'd pass the char itself to your Vogias function - no need for pass by reference if you don't want to change it.  Safer too.  Also, 1 loop would suffice if you are careful on how you copy.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66755490/is-there-a-way-to-delete-a-repeated-character-in-a-string-using-pointers-in-c/66756323#comment118005580_66756323

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]", s);` is worse than [`gets()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used).  Use `fgets()`.

Comment: Should 'oOoO' compress to `'o'` or `'O'` or what?

Comment: That 'oOoO' case  should be transformed in 'oO'. But this is a simple question so there isn't need to complicate

Comment: What about `aoao` ? Should that get transformed to `ao` ? And should `aba` be transformed to `ab` ? The specification is not precise enough.

Comment: *In portuguese we don't have words with two consecutive vowels* really? What about **coordenador**, **coordenação**, **coordenadas**, **cooperar**...

Comment: You got me @chqrlie. You know better my languange than me XD. Extra points for you.

Comment: @IvoLims: Vamos beber um pouco de **álcool** da próxima vez em Lisboa :)

Comment: Are these characters vowels? `âáã`

Comment: Yes it is @VladFeinstein and also à,é,è,ê,í,ì,õ,ó,ò,ô,û,ú,ù.

Comment: @IvoLims but your code is not checking for them!

Comment: This question is just for normal vowels (a,e,i,o,u) the simple answear of chqrlie will have the job done in this first step. I will try to implement a function that does all that in a near future. But thanks for trying to help me @VladFeinstein

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is too complicated: there is no need for nested loops for this task and you do not set the null terminator when shortening the string.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int retiraVogaisRep(char *s) {
    int i, j;      // use 2 running indices
    char c, last = 0;
    for (i = j = 0; (c = s[i]) != '\0'; i++) {
        if (c != last || !strchr("aeiouAEIOU", c))
            s[j++] = last = c;
    }
    s[j] = '\0';   // set the null terminator
    return i - j;  // return the number of bytes removed
}

int main() {
    char s[100];

    printf("Digite uma String:\n");

    // read the user input safely with `fgets()`
    if (!fgets(s, sizeof s, stdin))
        return 1;

    // strip the trailing newline if any
    s[strcspn(s, "\n")] = '\0';

    // remove duplicate consecutive vowels
    int res = retiraVogaisRep(s);

    printf("A String sem duplicados fica assim ' %s ' e foram retiradas %d vogais.\n", s, res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This one is almost perfect the only thing is the 'OoO' case that you talked about.

Comment: @IvoLims: what is the expected behavior for `OoO`?

Comment: Ty for the help @chqrlie

Comment: I like the `return i - j;`.  No need to increment 3 variables.

Answer (score 2):

#### Remove consecutive duplicate vowels

You should use tolower function from ctype.h to check for vowels, that include the letter 'y', see below working code:

You can store previous character in `prev` and compare it to the current character, as you are case insensitive you store the tolower version.

```c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int Vogais(char c){
    return (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u' || c == 'y') ;
}

int retiraVogaisRep (unsigned char *s){
    if (*s == NULL)
        return 0;
        
    unsigned char t[256];
    memset(t, 0, sizeof(t));
    int res = 0;
    int j = 0;
    t[0] = s[0];
    char prev = tolower(s[0]);
    int len = strlen(s);

    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        char c = tolower(s[i]);
        if (Vogais(c) && c == prev)
            ++res;
        else
            t[j++] = s[i];
        prev = c;

    }
    memcpy(s, t, sizeof(t));
    return res;
}

int main(){
    char s[256];
    printf("Digite uma String:\n");
    scanf("%255[^\n]", s);
    int res = retiraVogaisRep(s);
    printf("Da String ' %s ' podem ser retiradas %d vogais.\n", s,res);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nope try this example 'Estaa e umaa string coom duuuplicadoos' should be 'Esta e uma string com duplicados' and I am getting with your code 'Esta  um string'

Comment: I'm afraid you should not assume that the argument string has a size of 20 bytes. You should replace the string characters in place and make sure you null terminate the shortened string. `scanf("%20[^\n]", s);` should be `scanf("%19[^\n]", s);`. The input buffer should probably be made larger. `if (*s == NULL)` is incorrect: use `if (*s == '\0')` instead.

Comment: @IvoLims: your example string is too long for the 20 byte buffer in `main()`. Your code has undefined behavior for overlong input.

Comment: Your approach will consider "Oo" to have a duplicate vowel: I'm not sure this is expected, and the OP's code certainly does not do that.

Comment: In portuguese we don't have words with two consecutive vowels. And if thouse cases exist, they should be ignored in the context of this problem.

Comment: @chqrlie Isn't "Oo" has a duplicate vowel? The OP's function `Vogais` defines both `O` and `o`...

Comment: @user14063792468: the OP's code tries to remove duplicated characters that are uppercase or lowercase vowels. `O` and `o` is not the same character. By duplicate, it seems the OP means identical consecutive letters.

Comment: @chqrlie Just looked closer on the OP's code. You are right. He seem to remove only identical characters. I should edit my question.

Comment: Try again with a buffer of 256 chars. See my edit

Comment: The number in the `scanf` conversion is the maximum number of characters to use for the conversion, so it does not include the null terminator. Hence you must write `scanf("%255[^\n]", s);` It is simpler to use `fgets()`.

Comment: I was thinking about this and then I tested with 20* letters as input and there was no problem, how comes?  (*original buffer size from OP)

Comment: You were lucky... The stack might be aligned on 8 or 16 byte boundaries so there is space for some extra bytes after the array before you touch anything risky such as the caller's frame pointer or the return address. see https://godbolt.org/z/9EosdMqxz

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < strlen(s); i++) {` obliges code to compute `strlen(s)` each iteration.  Each call cost O(string_length) time.  Compiler cannot, in this case, assume `strlen(s)` returns the same value each time.

Comment: It is true if you compile without optimization flags. Any compiler with optimization flag would store strlen(s) in a register, already tested a while ago with gcc.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL: I'm afraid you are mistaken. In this particular case, you modify the array pointed to by `s` and the compiler cannot easily determine that `strlen(s)` will stay the same for each call. Recomputing `strlen(s)` at each iteration is a classic mistake and expecting the optimizer to correct it is a bad assumption. Furthermore this idiom sets a bad example for beginners.

Comment: I modify t, not s, I just checked on godbolt with O3, but I agree for the bad example it sets

Answer (score 2):

The question tag is `C`, but I will not post the actual code here.

The pseudocode:

```
function is_vowel(int c) {...}

start loop c = <src>
 if next_char is past the last char then quit loop;
 if is_vowel(c) and c == next_char and is_vowel(next_char)
  then continue;
 else
  copy c to <dst>
```

You should elaborate on this, as the above is possibly having small issues. Nevertheless, I think this answer is somewhat shorter and gives an insight.

**Update**

The above is definitly have an issue, in that the next char does not copied to the output. The mistake is easy to correct, so I will leave it up to OP.

**Update**

Edited above code to indicate that OP wants to remove only identical duplicates. So, the case of a charcter is important.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than a triple nested loop, consider a single walk down the string, looking for repeats.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int Vogais(unsigned char s) {
    if (s == 'A' || s == 'a' || s == 'E' || s == 'e'
     || s == 'I' || s == 'i' || s == 'O' || s == 'o'
     || s == 'U' || s == 'u') return 1;
    return 0;
}

int retiraVogaisRep(char *s) {
  unsigned char *us = (unsigned char *) s;
  unsigned char *dest = us;
  int res = 0;
  int prior = EOF;
  while (*us) {
    while (toupper(*us) == prior) {
      us++;
      res++;
    }
    prior = Vogais(*us) ? toupper(*us) : EOF;
    *dest++ = *us++;
  }
  *dest = '\0';
  return res;
}

int main() {
  char buf[100] = "OoFreedaa";
  printf("%d\t", retiraVogaisRep(buf));
  printf("<%s>\n", buf);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
3   <OFreda>
```

Comment: You might need a cast in `unsigned char *us = s;` to silence compiler warnings.

Comment: It is unclear if `Oo` should produce `O` as the OP answered you question with a curious example: `oOoO` should convert to `oO`...

Comment: @chqrlie Agreed, quite a _curious_ function goal.

Answer (score 1):

Retaining the uppercase, using the Kernighan-copy

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

size_t remove_duplicate_vowels(char *str)
{
int old,new;
size_t dst,src;

old = 0;
for(dst=src=0; str[dst] = str[src]; old=new, src++ ) {
        new = toupper( str[dst] );
        if ( !strchr( "AEIOU",  new )) { // Not a vowel
                dst++; continue;
                }
        if ( new != old ) { // Not a repetition
                dst++; continue;
                }
        }

return src - dst;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
char test[] = "Aaa bbBb CccCC d eEeee!";
char *arg;
size_t ret;

arg = argv[1] ?  argv[1] : test;

ret = remove_duplicate_vowels(arg);

fprintf(stderr, "[%zu]: %s\n", ret, arg);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very strange that I don't get any credits for this, since it is the correct&simplest solution.

Comment: Unfortunally , I dont vote down competitors. But the gap is huge.

Comment: Although your function works, I am not allowed to change the type of the function in the context of the problem and I only marked an example of a answear for my question.

Comment: What do you mean by `change the type of the function` ?

Comment: The signature of the function shouldn't be change.

Comment: Aha! You mean the `int` vs `size_t` thing? It is trivial: just change `size_t` back to `int`. (but: `size_t` is  marginally *better* in this case; using ints for sizes is just a bad habit)

Comment: I know that, but my teachers insist to use that way because blah,blah,...And the other responses were quicker to appear. But your answear is cool too, thanks for helping (I already upvoted this one XD)